# Retrieve DOM data from site

Tags: c#, java, javascript, dom, screen-scraping

Is there any chance to retrieve DOM results when I click older posts from the site:

http://www.facebook.com/FamilyGuy

using C# or Java? I heard that it is possible to execute a script with `onclick` and get results.  How I can execute this script:

```
onclick="(JSCC.get('j4eb9ad57ab8a19f468880561') && JSCC.get('j4eb9ad57ab8a19f468880561').getHandler())(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `older posts` link sends an `Ajax` request and appends the response to the page. (I'm not sure. You should check the page source).

You can emulate this behavior in `C#`, `Java`, and `JavaScript` (you already have the code for javascript).

Edit:

It seems that `Facebook` uses some sort of internal APIs (`JSCC`) to load the content and it's undocumented.

I don't know about `Facebook` Developers' APIs (you may want to check that first) but if you want to emulate exactly what happens in your browser then you can use [`TamperData`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) to intercept `GET` requests when you click on `more posts` link and find the request **URL** and it's **parameters**.

After you get this information you have to `Login` to your account in your application and get the authentication cookie.

`C#` sample code as you requested:

```
private CookieContainer GetCookieContainer(string loginURL, string userName, string password)
{
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(loginURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    var responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    responseReader.Close();

    // Now you may need to extract some values from the login form and build the POST data with your username and password.
    // I don't know what exactly you need to POST but again a TamperData observation will help you to find out.
    string postData =String.Format("UserName={0}&Password={1}", userName, password); // I emphasize that this is just an example.

    // cookie container
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();

    // post the login form
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(loginURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

    // write the form values into the request message
    var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
    requestWriter.Close();

    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
    return cookies;
}
```

Then you can perform `GET` requests with the cookie you have, on the `URL` you've got from analyzing that `JSCC.get().getHandler()` requests using `TamperData`, and eventually you'll get what you want as a response stream:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = GetCookieContainer(url, userName, password);
var responseStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

---

You can also use [`Selenium`](http://seleniumhq.org/) for browser automation. It also has `C#` and `Java` APIs (I have no experience using `Selenium`).

Comment: Can you provide me simple code in c# how to emulate that request?

Comment: Since I don't have a facebook account, you would somehow share the page source (in pastebin.com for example).

Comment: this doesn't include the page contents loaded by javascript. `File -> Save Page As...`, post the content.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook loads it's content dynamically with AJAX. You can use a tool like Firebug to examine what kind of request is made, and then replicate it.

Or you can use a browser render engine like webkit to process the JavaScript for you and expose the resulting HTML:
http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/